# mongodb find in order of last record to first

Tags: javascript, mongodb

My project inserts a large number of historical data documents into a history collection, since they are never modified the order is correct (as no updating goes on) but backwards for retrieving.

I'm using something like this to retrieve the data in pages of 20 records.

```
var page = 2;

hStats_collection.find({name:name},{_id:0, name:0}).limit(20).skip(page*20).toArray( function(err, doc) {
});
```

After reading my eyes dry, $sort is no good, and it appears the best way to reverse the order that the above code retrieves is to add an index via a time stamp element in the document, of which I already have a useful item called `started` (seconds since epoc) and need to create an index for it.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-index/
The docs say I can do something like:

```
hStats_collection.createIndex( { started: -1 } )
```

How do I change my .find() code above to find `name` and reference the `started` index so the results come back newest to oldest (as oposed to the natural find() oldest to newest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hStats_collection.find({name:name},{_id:0, name:0})`**`.sort({ started:-1 })`**`.limit(20).`

Comment: That does not require index, but will probably be very slow without it. Try doing it without an index and look if the query time is appropriate for you. If it takes more than a couple of seconds, consider creating an index.

Comment: Ah I see it works fine, i was confused by the way the docs said there is a 32mb limit, this limit only applies if there is no index of 'started' - missed that bit. Thankyou!

Comment: Glad I was able to help! If you hit the 32mb limit, you definitely have to create an index. And it's generally a good practice to create index on fields you use for searching/sorting.